# Scripts that include login credentials to automate the login page

Tags: javascript, vbscript, batch-file

I have one URL when i am browsing it it is asking me username and password. I want to make it automated so i want scripts by which i can pass the user credentials in that scripts so when URL browse that page automatically take these credentials and logged in.

Answer (score 0):

some sites accept the username and password in the url, such as

`http://username:password@www.stackoverflow.com`

note that due to security concerns, this would have to be enabled on some machines. IE now ships with this functionality [disabled as default](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;%5bLN%5d;834489)

that page also has some workarounds that you may be able to use, depending on the sites.

Comment: did you include the `http://` ? if I go to the link, exactly as written, I get a warning from Firefox that I'm attempting to log into stackoverflow.com with the username `username` but the website doesn't require authentication